# Extra White Space Top of Webpage

Tags: css, whitespace, margin, removing-whitespace

I created a wrapper div for my site to contain the entire contents of the body, but for some reason, I have extra white space above the wrapper div. I can't exactly pinpoint why this is happening; I put zero padding and zero margins for both the body and the wrapper div:

```
<body onload="init()" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:#000000; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<div id="pagecontent">
<nav id="navlogo" style="margin:10px;">Some Navigation Stuff
</nav></div></div></body>
```

(The Page Content Div holds all of the webpage's elements and centers them.)
I also have this CSS for the page content:

```
#pagecontent
{
margin: 0px auto;
width: 1044px;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 15px black;
background-color:#000000;
}
```

I tried using negative margins of -10px on the wrapper div, and that worked out; is that the only way to get rid of this white space?

Comment: need to see more code, the stuff you posted is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<nav id="navlogo" style="margin:10px;">`

This margin includes margin-top:10px  - that is the issue.
`margin:10px;` = `margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:10px;`

to get around this you could change it to:

```
margin:10px;margin-top:0;
```

or to make the navbar go to the top just change `margin:10px;` to `padding:10px;`